# I have a subarray, how can I get ALL the documents where there is a match

Tags: mongodb

I have these 2 collections:

country

```
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820425",
      "name": "USA"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820422",
      "name": "PERU"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820423",
      "name": "COLOMBIA"
    }
```

travel_reservation

```
    {
      "name_person": "pablo rojas",
      "countrys_id": [
        {
          "country_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820425"
        },
        {
          "country_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820423"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name_person": "Anuel",
      "countrys_id": [
        {
          "country_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820422"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name_person": "Laura",
      "countrys_id": []
    }
```

I want to group in the array of `countrys_id` of the collection `travel_reservation` using the field `country_id` that is the `_id` contained in `country`.

I want an output like this

Output desired:

```
[
    {
      "name_person":  "pablo rojas",
      "countrys":[
        {
          "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820425",
          "country": "USA"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820423",
          "country": "COLOMBIA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name_person":  "Anuel",
      "countrys":[
        {
          "_id": "5fbc7cc705253c2da4820422",
          "country": "PERU"
        },
      ]
    }    
    {
      "name_person":  "Laura",
      "countrys":[
 
      ]
    }      
]
```

but I don't know what I'm doing wrong? this is my code:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/P7JDBdUNn0F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is so appreciated.

- You need the empty array list also Eg :"Laura". So when you unwind, the default behavior is to remove null or empty array `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:false`. Since we need it, we need to make it as true.
- `$lookup` to join collections
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element of the array
- `$group` to regroup because we already deconstructed the array using `$unwind`

And working script is

```
db.travel_reservation.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$countrys_id",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "country",
      let: {
        ci: "$countrys_id.country_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$ci"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "join",
      
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      join: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$join",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      countrys: {
        $push: "$join"
      },
      name_person: {
        $first: "$name_person"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/21w5KjEyzYN)**

The reason why your lookup not working is, variable mismatched of `let: { ci: "$countrys_id._id" }` and `$eq: [ "$country._id", "$$ci" ]`

Comment: thank you!!Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help, and I'm learning. One last question, how could I leave the base structure and just add the `countrys` field?

Comment: We will do a small adjustment inside pipeline, Just to add `$project`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/bM6AARfsM11

Comment: you are a genius and very intelligent THANK YOU. I meant that if I have `n` fields, I must write one by one to display it or else it will only show what is in the `$group`. My question is if there is any way to avoid having to write the properties I want one by one displayed.

Comment: Do you expect this https://mongoplayground.net/p/SlvWtJJksEt

Comment: @yavg may I make this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want exact all object from country then try,

- `$llokup` join `country` collection
- `$project` to remove `countrys_id` field

```
db.travel_reservation.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "country",
      localField: "countrys_id.country_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "countrys"
    }
  },
  { $project: { countrys_id: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e0ENUQesWLI)

---

Second way if you want current `countrys_id` field's object then try,

- `$llokup` join `country` collection
- add name in `countrys`,  `$map` to iterate loop of `countrys_id` array and `$reduce` to find that country name and merge with current object using `$mergeObjects`

```
db.travel_reservation.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "country",
      localField: "countrys_id.country_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "country"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      name_person: 1,
      countrys: {
        $map: {
          input: "$countrys_id",
          as: "c",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$c",
              {
                name: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$country",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $eq: ["$$this._id", "$$c.country_id"] },
                        "$$this.name",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cjz9oB4X5qo)